# Syntax error near table_name

Tags: c#, sql

So I have this code to insert values from text-box into my database, but every time i execute my code and enters my data i get this message

> "Syntax Error near keyword user"

```
string Connectionstring = @"DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Bank_System.mdf;Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True";    
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring);
cnn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into user values('" + int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text  + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text +  "','" + int.Parse(textBox6.Text) + "')", cnn);
SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
dr1.Close();                
MessageBox.Show(" Record inserted ", " information inserted");
cnn.Close();
```

Comment: `User` is a reserved work in SQL Server (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx).  You should name your table something else, such as `users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`USER` is a [reserved keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in T-SQL. You should use it with square brackets like `[USER]`. However, the best solution is to change the name to a non-reserved word.

But more important, please use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

By the way, I don't understand why you used `ExecuteReader` for an `INSERT` command. Looks like you just need to use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`.

```
using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
using(SqlCommand cmd1 = cnn.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [USER] VALUE(@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6)";
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", int.Parse(textBox1.Text));
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", textBox2.Text);
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", textBox3.Text);
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", textBox4.Text);
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", textBox5.Text);
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", int.Parse(textBox6.Text));
   cnn.Open();

   int count = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
   if(count > 0)
      MessageBox.Show("Record inserted");
}
```

Comment: I have added `[USER]` in the CommandText, If incorrect please revert back

Comment: @Satpal I mentioned about it but forget to add it :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You try to concatenate int to string. The error is here: int.Parse(textBox1.Text) -> you need to convert to string after you test if is integer. 
Try this for test : int.Parse(textBox1.Text).ToString() to see if this is your problem. 
You try gather string to an integer by using:

`"insert into user values('" + int.Parse(textBox1.Text)` .... 
=> string + int

Correct is:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into user values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text  + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text +  "','" + textBox6.Text + "')", cnn);
```

try to validate if textBox1.Text and textBox6.Text before concatenate but is recommended to use parameters.

Comment: You have a point about not using single quotes with numeric values but this isn't the real problem here. Also parameterized queries will handle this automaticly.